# Find gridview from parent ascx control using client side code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a user control call parent.ascx and i load inside a child.ascx. In the child control i have a gridview and i want to access it using javascript from parent ascx control. I am using the following code but it doesnt found it. Any help?.

```
      var grid = document.getElementById("<%= child_grdrisk.ClientID %>");

   alert(grid.rows.length);
```

Comment: Interesting, parent is loaded inside child! Whatever, Rows is a property of the gridview control and when you get it using javascript it is not GridView at all, just an HTML element and those properties are not available. You have to parse the HTML to grab the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nr of rows like this:

```
var rowsCount = <%=child_grdrisk.Rows.Count %>;
```

or you could store the nr of rows in a hidden field and get the nr of rows from it:

```
hiddenField1.Value = child_grdrisk.Rows.Count.ToString();

var rowsCount = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenField1.ClientID %>');
```

or you can use jQuery:

```
var rowsCount = $("#<%= grdrisk.ClientID %> tr").length;
```

Comment: The point is to take the Grid inside the var and i do not want to display only the rows :)